Are the requirements for a field higher than for a vector space?
My background: finished Linear Algebra 1, learning Linear Algebra 2 as of now.
I find myself appreciating the definition of a vector space and the axioms that it has to satisfy much more, as they make dealing with higher dimensions vector spaces easier and more feasible, which lead me realise my unfamiliarity with fields until now.
The fields I know of are real, complex, or rational numbers. My understanding is a field provides the scalars for a vector space. And fields seem to have to satisfy addition and multiplication with their inverses and being closed to addition and multiplication. I assume we define vectors over fields for usefulness, since dealing with objects  such as matrices but defined over $\mathbb Z$ for example will have much less usefulness, since they carry less information and would be restricted in the geometric meaning they deliver.
So I have 2 questions from here:

When we define an object that satisfies the vector space properties over numbers that are not a field, example matrices over $\mathbb Z$, what do we call this group with the its (objects addition)(no idea what will this be called) and scalar multiplication properties, what is the use of making such a restriction if we where to do so (other than for the sake of defining such object)?
And if we were to do so, how would the transformation from the vector addition and scalar multiplication to the new operations work? What if the entries are from $\mathbb R$ and the scalar is from $\mathbb Z$, are we considering what used to be vector addition to be over the field of $\mathbb R$ but the product over $\mathbb Z$? Would allowing entries from a field lead to some complications and we would need to add more restrictions?

Is the requirement to be a field higher than the requirement to be a vector space? I can't think of a way a group = the field defined  over the field with its 2 basic operations and not resulting in a vector space?



In some sense, yes. Every field is a vector space over itself, and also over its sub-fields. However, there are plenty of vector spaces which have no natural field structure.

what does having no natural field structure mean?

For a specific example, consider the space of functions (arbitrary or, say, continuous, smooth, etc.) $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$. It's a real vector space, but it doesn't have inverses under the usual multiplication operation: $1/f$ only lies in the space if $f$ is nonzero everywhere (as opposed to being the zero function).

since I did not learn about fields by  definition, it is a bit hard to tell what is a natural field structure , the natural structures are the ones like R C Q ?(I need to read about this )If I compare what you mentioned to those fields which  are invariable everywhere but at zero , here if f is a function  like ((x-2)(x-3)(x)   1/((x-2)(x-3)(x) _not invertible  at 2 3 0 in the function provided so can't form a field since it is not invertible every where excluding 0?

".when we define an object that satisfies the vector space properties over numbers that are not a field ,example matrices over Z what do we call this group with the its( objects addition)(no idea what will this be called ) and scalar multiplication properties" <<< We call that a Z-module but it turns out to be exactly the same thing as a commutative group, because for an integer $n$ and a module element $x$, we have the equality $nx = x+...+x$, so in a way, multiplication by an integer is just shorthand for repeated addition.

thank you all for the amazing insight any new answers are more than welcome and all the answers where equally helpful and hard to chose from ,much appreciated

For the first question:
As mentioned by the other answers, the generalization of the vector spaces to structures over rings which are not fields are called modules. (It's generally exactly the same rules, you just don't have a field but a ring of scalars, i.e. no multiplicative inverses).
(In my linear algebra course, the professor even defined first semigroups, groups, rings, then modules, and proved a lot of properties for them, and then in the first lecture of the second semester we finally got the definition of fields ("a ring where every element except 0 has a multiplicative inverse"), and "a module over a field is called a vector space".)
Many of the properties you'll learn for vector spaces generalize to modules, but not all of them – e.g. not every finitely generated module has a basis (i.e. a way of uniquely writing coordinates), so you don't have the clear concept of a "dimension". Some of the properties which do generalize are a lot harder to prove for modules than for vector spaces, so there is some merit in starting with the easier special case first.
For your second question:
A structure (e.g. abelian group) becoming a module (or vector space) is in some way "easier" than it becoming a ring (or field) [meaning that there are a lot of structures that are modules and not rings, or vector spaces and not fields], but on the other hand you first need a ring (or field) to even define what a module (or vector space) over that ring (field) is.
But if we take the ring $\mathbb Z$ (the integers), then even any abelian group will be enough to fulfill the axioms for a  $\mathbb Z$-module (with the scalar multiplication $n · x := \underbrace{x + x + ... + x}_{n\text{ times}}$).
If you got larger (or "more complicated") rings / fields, making something into a module / vector space over that ring/field is more difficult – but there are plenty of known ways to construct new ones.
Some examples:
For any ring $R$:

$R$ itself if always an $R$-module (with the normal multiplication used as scalar multiplication).
Certain subsets of $R$ called ideals are $R$-modules (with the normal multiplication used as scalar multiplication). (For fields, there is only the {0}-ideal, not very interesting. For $\mathbb Z$, these are just $k·\mathbb Z$, i.e. the sets of multiples of any number $k$.)
The cartesian products $R^n$ (with the component-wise addition and component-wise scalar multiplication) are $R$-modules.
The matrix spaces $R^{n×m}$ are $R$-modules (with component-wise addition and scalar multiplication).
The ring of polynomials $R[X]$ in one variable and coefficients in $R$ (with just the coefficient-wise addition and scalar multiplication) is an $R$-module. The same is true for polynomials in multiple variables.
For any set $X$, the set of functions from $X$ to $R$ is an $R$-module (with the point-wise addition and point-wise scalar multiplication).
If you have any larger ring $R'$ with an embedding $R \subset R'$, then $R'$ also becomes an $R$-module with its normal addition and multiplication.

Also, all $R'$- modules automatically become $R$-modules too.
This even works if you just have a ring-homomorphism $f : R \to R'$ (you just define $a · x := f(a)·x$).



In all of these cases, if you take a field $F$ instead of a ring, you get a vector space. The last point is how all vector spaces over $\mathbb C$ automatically become also vector spaces over $\mathbb R$ and $\mathbb Q$, as well as $\mathbb Z$-modules.

The set of invertible matrices with integer entries is an extremely important structure in higher mathematics. The $2\times2$ case is fundamental for the study of modular forms, which were at the base of the resolution by Wiles and Taylor of Fermat's Last Theorem.
It's not a vector space, not even a module, since it isn't closed under addition (the sum of two invertible matrices need not be invertible).
In another direction, there are lots of fields other than the rationals, the reals, and the complex numbers, and their study is also very important in higher mathematics. Some search phrases are number fields, $p$-adic fields, finite fields, fields of rational functions, ....

this seems really interesting to read about , thanks for the amazing resources I will go and search about them


We usually call those objects modules, provided that your "numbers" form a ring; i.e. has invertible addition and (not necessarily invertible) multiplication. They are generalizations of vector spaces with many interesting properties, and also provide useful tools for studying representation theory (which, roughly speaking, allows you to "translate" group actions on a vector space to linear transformations)

Indeed, every field is automatically a 1-dimensional vector space over itself (with the basis vector being any non-zero element), so you need to meet more requirements to become a field.



I can't think of a way a group= the field defined over the field with its 2 basic operations and not resulting in a vector space?

I am not quite sure what you mean by this. Any non-abelian group, for example, would not result in a vector space.

we define vectors over fields for usefulness since dealing with objects such matrices but defined over Z for example will have much less usefulness since they carry less information and would be restricted in the geometric meaning they deliver

It depends on what you mean by "usefulness" really. While you get much nicer properties by imposing more restrictions to the structure you study, you are also limiting the range to which your results apply.

for the line you mentioned I meant if I take a group with 2 operation being the normal multiplication and addition , where the elements of the group belong to a field and I define the operation over the same field is there a way to not get a vector space, and because I could not think of such for the fields I know of I assumed the requirement would be higher in some sense

"if I take a group with 2 operation being the normal multiplication and addition", well, groups aren't typically endowed with addition... so I assume you mean field? That would be my point (2), that every field is automatically a vector space over itself

yeah I was  explaining because I got a bit confused your point 2 aligned as an answer for the line I wrote but was   followed with '' non-abelian group  not resulting in a vector space.   so I thought non ablelian group was a counter example for a field not forming a vector space

I thank you for this well detailed  answer i will let the question open for a while to gain more insights
